# Why is my MapKit map not loading?

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I'm using a MapView.
It works fine on the simulator but when I test on a device the map doesn't seem to load. (or does load but takes a very long time sometime).

All I do to use the MapView is just grabbing an instance of MapView and put it in the view through Interface Builder.

Is there anyway I can do to force the map to load?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Wifi conection?
It's strange because the map usually does not take much time to load.
I hope you can find the reason